# How to write the Xpath for selecting a table from the following example + good Xpath cheatsheet available?

Tags: php, python, html, ruby, xpath

Needing some instructions on Xpath.  I have something along the following lines in terms of HTML.  How would I extract the table following the first paragraph with an image?

```
<p align="center">
    <img src="some_image.gif" alt="Some Title">
</p>
<table width="500" border="1" class="textstyle" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">
            <b>Label</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            Text
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            Text
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            Text
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            Text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<blockquote>
    <p class="textstyle">
        Text.
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

Obviously I'd like to see how to write the xpath for this, however I would further like to understand my options via some kind of an abbreviated list / cheatsheet of what options exist for xpath.  I was considering using something along the lines of this:

```
//table[preceding-sibling::p[contains(align(), "center")
```

or perhaps something that would allow me to say a p that's centered with an img in it, however I'm just not sure where to go to get a nice comprehensive list vs an actual writeup that explains all the gory details.

Comment: This firefox addon can help: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/

Comment: Thanks for that addon.  Very useful.  I would sure like to see this for Safari and updated to make it a little more straight forward to use with FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//p[img])[1]/following-sibling::table[1]
```

This selects the `table` that is the first `table` - following sibling of the first `p` in the document that has an `img` child.

**I recommend using the [XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) -- a tool that has helped many thousands of people learn XPath the fun way**.

Comment: The addon that @mshsayem noted above was really nice to use to experiment with your xpath.  I was able to coax it into working with Firefox 11 as well.

Comment: @ylluminate: The XPath Visualizer has a FF version, so using FF isn't a problem at all. I believe that the XPath Visualizer provides better learning support, because it allows the evaluation of *any* XPath expression -- not only XPath expressions that select only nodes. Another crucial features that only few such tools have, is highlighting the selected nodes inline in the XML document.

Comment: Really?  The link you gave seems to be dated to 2001 and I didn't see any real way to load it up in FF per se like an extension, but rather simply a page.  It also failed when I attempted to load up an html file.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ylluminate: 2001 is the first year the XPath Visualizer (XPV) was released -- since then it has had several versions. The XPV works on well-formed XML documents (including XHTML) -- as XPath is a language for navigating through XML documents -- not general HTML. XPV isn't an extension -- it is just an html file that you open with your browser. Then you can specify the path to the XML file you want to issue XPath expressions against. When the XML file is loaded, you enter your XPath expression and it is evaluated, hilighting the selected nodes within the loaded XML document.

Comment: I've noticed that there are also sometimes div's inside of these cells.  I have found that doing something like this: `(//p[img])[1]/following-sibling::table[1]//tr[td[2]]//text()` will indeed give me every single element content in text format... however I would have to programmatically watch for the flag row keyword, then set a value if there are contents, etc. all they way through the entire table.  Not really a huge problem, but I am guessing there is a better way in xpath to do this?

Comment: @ylluminate: Please, ask a new question for any new problem. The comments format is not the best when explaining XML or XPath problems.

Comment: done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386218/extracting-table-cell-text-contents-with-xpath-in-rows-for-consumption