# Extracting table cell text contents with xpath in rows for consumption?

Tags: php, python, html, ruby, xpath

I have something along the following lines in terms of HTML.  I would like to extract the various contents of the table cells, however I discovered that there are some embedded divs occasionally in the cells and perhaps other oddities that I'm not sure of yet:

```
<p align="center">
    <img src="some_image.gif" alt="Some Title">
</p>
<TABLE WIDTH=500 BORDER=1 class=textwhite ALIGN=center CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
<TR>
<TD colspan=4 ALIGN=center><b>Title</b></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=center>Title</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>date</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>value</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>value</TD>
</TR><TR>
  <TD ALIGN=center>Title2</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
  <TD ALIGN=center><div class=redtext>----</div></TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR><TR>
  <TD ALIGN=center>Title3</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=center><div class=yellowtext>value</div></TD>
  <TD ALIGN=center><div class=redtext>value</div></TD>
  <TD ALIGN=center>value<SUP>6</SUP></TD>
</TR><TR>
  <TD ALIGN=center>Title4</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=center><div class=bluetext>value</div></TD>
  <TD ALIGN=center><div class=redtext>value</div></TD>
  <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR></TABLE>

<blockquote>
    <p class="textstyle">
        Text.
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

My first impulse was to extract ALL element texts and just programmatically slice it up.  I would watch for Title1, Title2, etc. to know when a row starts and then if a "----" is found meaning no value, just skip this row and move on.  However, I realized that there is probably a better way of handling this with xpath directly.

How could this be solved with xpath so as to essentially give each cell's final child text content vs having to walk into each div if it exists?  Or is there a more xpath like way to approach this?

Obviously I'm attempting to have the most flexible solution that will not be brittle if other unexpected elements crop up, even though they are unlikely.

Comment: Why not tell us the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is simply the contents of each cell.  Ultimately this will be stored in an array of hashes such that the "Title1", "Title2", etc. will be the name of each hash. Then if there is a value in each cell following in the row they will be additional values in that hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The provided text isn't well-formed XML document, therefore XPath isn't applicable**.

If you correct and covert it to a well-formed xml document as the one below, an expression like this might be useful:

```
/*/TABLE//TD//text()
```

or even:

```
//TABLE//TD//text()
```

---

Here is a wellformed XML document, constructed from the provided HTML:

```
<html>
    <p align="center">
        <img src="some_image.gif" alt="Some Title"/>
    </p>
    <TABLE WIDTH="500" BORDER="1" class="textwhite" ALIGN="center" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="4" ALIGN="center">
                <b>Title</b>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD ALIGN="center">Title</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">date</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">value</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">value</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD ALIGN="center">Title2</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center"></TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">
                <div class="redtext">----</div>
            </TD>
            <TD>&#xA0;</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD ALIGN="center">Title3</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">
                <div class="yellowtext">value</div>
            </TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">
                <div class="redtext">value</div>
            </TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">value
                <SUP>6</SUP>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD ALIGN="center">Title4</TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">
                <div class="bluetext">value</div>
            </TD>
            <TD ALIGN="center">
                <div class="redtext">value</div>
            </TD>
            <TD>&#xA0;</TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <blockquote>
        <p class="textstyle">         Text.     </p>
    </blockquote>
</html>
```

Comment: The key here is the //text().  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you don't want to walk the divs, but here is my solution using lxml, which I highly recommend:

```
import re
from cStringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

def getTable(html, table_xpath, rows_xpath, cells_xpath):
    """Get a table on a webpage"""
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    # Build document tree and get table
    root = etree.parse(StringIO(html), parser)
    table = root.find(table_xpath)
    if table == None:
        print 'No table.'
        return []
    rows = table.findall(rows_xpath)
    document = []
    def cleanText(text):
        """Clean up text by replacing line breaks and tabs. """
        return re.sub(r'[\r\n\t]+','',str(text).strip())
    # iterate over the table rows and collect text from each cell.
    for r in rows:
        cells = r.findall(cells_xpath)
        rowdata = []
        for c in cells:
            text = ''
            it = c.itertext()
            for i in it:
                text += cleanText(i) + ' '
            rowdata.append(text)
        document.append(rowdata)
    return document


html = """
<html><head><title></title></head><body>
<p align="center">
    <img src="some_image.gif" alt="Some Title">
    </p>
    <TABLE WIDTH=500 BORDER=1 class=textwhite ALIGN=center CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
    <TR>
    <TD colspan=4 ALIGN=center><b>Title</b></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Title</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>date</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>value</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>value</TD>
    </TR><TR>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Title2</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center><div class=redtext>----</div></TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR><TR>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Title3</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center><div class=yellowtext>value</div></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center><div class=redtext>value</div></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>value<SUP>6</SUP></TD>
    </TR><TR>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Title4</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center><div class=bluetext>value</div></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center><div class=redtext>value</div></TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR></TABLE>   
</body>
</html>
"""
tp = "//table[@width='500']"
rt = "tr"
cp = "td[@align='center']"

doc = getTable(html, tp, rt, cp)
print repr(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your program is going to run into many problems as the input data is manipulated -- what if the case of 'title' changes, or there is a typo?

It's not really possible to make a rigorous solution to scraping someone else's website, as they can at no notice completely change everything. Better is normally to write tolerant and flexible code that at least tries to verify that its output is sane. In this case it's probably best to iterate over the results of '//table/tr', then inside this loop, process the td elements:

```
import lxml.etree
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring("<table><tr><td>test</td></tr><tr><td><div>test2</div></td></tr></table>")
stringify = lambda x : "".join(x.xpath(".//text()"))
for x in tree.xpath("//table/tr"):
    print "New row"
    for y in x.xpath("td"):
        print stringify(y)
```

Output:

```
New row
test
New row
test2
```

The following code will, however, get the list you ask for:

```
print map(stringify, tree.xpath("//table/tr/td"))
```

Output:

```
['test', 'test2']
```

This will find all text elements which are at all descended from a td which is a direct descendant of a tr which is in turn a direct descendant of a table.

(Simply asking for all text() elements will create some funny bugs when run on HTML which contains "<td>Foo <b>bar</b></td>" or similar.)